# Does ASIHttpRequest support IPv6-only?

Tags: ios, asihttprequest, ipv6

As apple will require [iOS App Store apps to support IPv6-only networks](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=05042016a) from June 1, I wonder if it is the time to abandon ASIHttpRequest.

Comment: `ASIHttpRequest` stopped updating since 2011, of course you should switch another modern networking library such as `AFNetworking`

Comment: yes, thanks, but it still works...

Comment: Never ever use deprecated / stopped developing libraries. Your app will break some days later. Also, `ASIHttpRequest` does not support iOS 9 network libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASIHttpRequest uses the CFStream APIs from CFNetwork, so it should work without any changes for IPv6-only networks.